# Middleware check the annotation from controller method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

Hello i want to check the annotation from a controller method in a middleware class.

My config:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, BackendDbContext context)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMiddleware<AuthMiddleware>();
    app.UseMvc();

    BackendDbInitializer.Init(context);
}
```

My Controller:

```cs
Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly BackendDbContext _context;

    public UserController(BackendDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [NoAuth]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

My Middleware:

```cs
public class AuthMiddleware 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        //Here i want to check if the called method in UserController have a annotation...
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

In the AuthMiddleware i want to check if the called method have a specific annotation.

Comment: Middlewares aren't aware of mvc context. You need to use filters to get called method information.

Comment: Can u give me an example?

Comment: Are you trying to write an Authentication or an Authorization middleware? ASP.NET Authentication middleware read the request credentials and set HttpContext.User. The Authorization attribute checks the User and grants or denies access.

Comment: I wish an Authentication

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this question is outdated, I came across the same question today, I'm using `Casbin.Net` package to implement RBAC for my asp dotnet core project, I need to implement an auth middleware which can recognize controllers with a `[Authorize]` annotation, so only these controllers need to check permission, the other controllers not, below are my code

[rbac with asp dotnet core using casbin](https://gist.github.com/xcaptain/920115af7bfe81a57fa58f62ea9e4887)

You can ignore the dependency inject and casbin parts, in `AuthzMiddleware.cs`, I use `context.User.Claims.Count() > 0` to check if the current request has passed a `Authentication` middleware.